# Outputting large XML file from SQL with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell, using, invoke-sqlcmd

I have a Powershell script that calls a stored procedure in SQL server and outputs the resulting XML directly to a file. It works for a smaller test file but falls down with the full size (~1.5gb file).

The stored procedure works fine. I can call it within SQL server - the problem is that I have to open it in the SQL server then manually save it to a file, then edit that file to remove newlines. When I run the script it falls down when it tries to delete the intermediary files at the end. However, when I run it line by line it falls down at the invoke-sql line.

```
#net use S: "\\processStore\projects"

# Create variables
$SQLquery = "DECLARE @return_value int; EXEC @return_value = [XML].[XMLdata];"
$outpath = "D:\MyDocuments\XML\XML files" 
$outfile = "TestOutput"

# Run the SQL command and store the object to a variable. Need to extend the timeout from the default.
$sql = invoke-sqlcmd -Database 'APP2021' -Query $SQLquery -serverinstance 'statdata' -QueryTimeout 100000

cd C:

# Store the SQL output as an interim text file
$sql.{XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B} | out-file -Filepath "$outpath\$outfile.txt" 

# Remove Linebreaks
(Get-Content "$outpath\$outfile.txt" -Raw).Replace("`r`n","") | Set-Content "$outpath\${outfile}_del.xml" -Force
format-xml "$outpath\${outfile}_del.xml" | Set-Content "$outpath\$outfile.xml" -Force

# Delete interim text files
del "$outpath\$outfile.txt"
del "$outpath\${outfile}_del.xml"
```

When running lines one by one the code falls down at the invoke-sqlcmd line with the error:

```
invoke-sqlcmd : A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote 
host.)
At line:1 char:8
+ $sql = invoke-sqlcmd -Database 'APP2021' -Query $SQLquery -serverinst ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Comment: Probably a timeout issue?

Comment: I expect it is something to do with this, but I'm unsure how to get around it? I cranked the QueryTimeout value to 400000 and it didn't help.

Comment: It seems as a timeout on the server.

Comment: Any idea what I can do to stop it timing out?

Comment: Is there any errors in server logs?

Comment: This is being run through powershell - if SQL is producing logs then it's on a remote machine somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about a remote server. If you're not supporting it then it would be good to ask its support team to cooperate since the error clearly states that the connection was closed by the remote host

Comment: In the absence of the server logs do you have any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change from 
invoke-sqlcmd -Database 'APP2021' -Query $SQLquery -serverinstance 'statdata' **-QueryTimeout 100000**

to

invoke-sqlcmd -Database 'APP2021' -Query $SQLquery -serverinstance 'statdata' **-QueryTimeout 0**

**Setting QueryTimeout =  0 will prevent the query from timing out**

Comment: Good suggestions, but I've just tried it and Powershell window crashes without error after a while.